# Not able to access a struct object properly inside fragment shader in Metal?

Tags: swift, fragment-shader, metal, metal-performance-shaders

I have two sections in my question:

**First Section**

I have a requirement where I have to pass a structure containing 3 values of a color (RGB) varying from 0 - 1 but it turns out whatever values Im receiving is different when I tested the code hardcoding the values.

Here is my fragment shader method

```
struct RGBColors {
    half red;
    half green;
    half blue;
};
fragment float4
samplingShader(RasterizerData in [[stage_in]],
               texture2d<half> colorTexture [[ texture(0) ]],
               const device struct RGBColors *color [[ buffer(0) ]]
)
{
    constexpr sampler textureSampler (mag_filter::linear,
                                      min_filter::linear,
                                      s_address::repeat,
                                      t_address::repeat,
                                      r_address::repeat);
        const half4 colorSample = colorTexture.sample (textureSampler, in.textureCoordinate);

    float4 outputColor = float4(0,0,0,0);

    half red = color->red;
    half blue = color->blue;
    half green = color->green;

    outputColor = float4(colorSample.r * red, colorSample.g * green, colorSample.b * blue, 0);

    return outputColor;
}
```

My swift structure looks like this,

```
struct RGBColors {
    var r: Float
    var g: Float
    var b: Float

    func floatBuffers() -> [Float] {
        return [r,g,b]
    }
}
```

I pass the buffers to the fragment like this,

```
let colors = color.floatBuffers()

    let colorBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: colors, length: 16, options: [])
    renderEncoder.setFragmentBuffer(colorBuffer, offset: 0, at: 0)
```

But if I change the parameter color in `const device struct RGBColors *color [[ buffer(0) ]]` to float3 like this `constant float3 *color [[ buffer(0) ]]` and access through `rgb` values it works properly.

**Second Section**

As you can see in my code that in
 `let colorBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: colors, length: 16, options: [])` the length is 16 but if I change it to

```
 `MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: colors[0]) * colors.count`
```

it is crashing and saying

```
`failed assertion `(length - offset)(12) must be >= 16 at buffer binding at index 0 for color[0].'`
```

Im not able to figure out what is happening. Can someone suggest me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swift `Float` type does not correspond to the Metal `half` type. To my knowledge, there's no good representation of `half` in Swift (or, for that matter, C or Objective-C). You're providing 3 32-bit values to something which is expecting 3 16-bit values. The values you're providing do not line up with with how the receiving code accesses them, so it's accessing sub-parts of the values.

So, I recommend switching from using `half` in your shader to using `float`, which is more easily represented in Swift.

Next, your `RGBColors` struct is basically just redundant with the built-in type `half3` or, if you took my above advice, `float3`. So, I recommend you just use `float3`. That type is even available in Swift if you `import simd`. In Metal (and C), you'd be able to access its members using either `.r`, `.g`, `.b` or `.x`, `.y`, `.z`, but Swift seems to only support the latter. Both languages support accessing the members using array subscript syntax.

As documented in the [`MemoryLayout` overview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/memorylayout), you should **not** use the `size` property or `size(ofValue:)` method when calculating buffer sizes or offsets. You should use `stride`/`stride(ofValue:)`. Furthermore, you shouldn't use the stride of one element of a compound type multiplied by the number of elements. You need to use the stride of the whole compound type. That's because the compiler can add padding to a compound type to maintain alignment requirements and the former technique does not take that into account.

One final note: in your shader, the `color` variable is only used to access a single color. That is, it's not an array of colors. So, you should probably declare it as a reference type rather than a pointer type. That lets the compiler know so it can generate better code.

```
const device float3 &color [[ buffer(0) ]]
```

Of course, then you'd need to change `color->` to `color.`.

Comment: That worked. But still I'm not able to figure out why I'm still getting crash if I use `MemoryLayout.stride(ofValue: colors)` and pass to the buffer  length of buffer Im getting crash as `failed assertion (length - offset)(8) must be >= 16 at buffer binding at index 0 for color[0].` But when I use `MemoryLayout.stride(ofValue: colors[0]) * colors.count` that worked for struct not for `float3` type parameter. Can you suggest me why?

Comment: The `float3` type has padding. Its stride is **not** equal to 3 times the size of a single `float`/`Float`. Check the Metal Shader Language spec (section 2.9, table 3) and you'll see that the size and alignment of `float3` is 16 bytes. That's why it's not valid to take the stride of one element and multiply it by the number of elements. You get the wrong result. As to `MemoryLayout.stride(ofValue: colors)` apparently giving a value of 8, that's because `colors` is a Swift array, which is not a simple buffer. It's an object with an unknown internal layout. Don't try to do that.